# Wrong heigth of view on orientation change

Tags: android, layout, android-manifest, orientation

I'm building an app and I'm trying to set up smart admob banners at the bottom of the app. At the bottom there is a FrameLayout that will act as an ad container.

I have 2 layout files, one for portrait and one for landscape. The portrait one contains a FrameLayout with height of 50dp and the landscape one has 32dp (as per google's guidelines).

This is working fine, but since my activity does a lot of stuff in onCreate, I had to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in my activity's configuration in the manifest in order to prevent calling onCreate every time the device is rotated.

However, now when my view is rotated, the FrameLayout (adContainer) stays 50dp high.

How can I force that particular layout to redraw from the XML on orientation change and get the correct height?

I've tried invalidating the FrameLayout in the `onConfigurationChanged` but my layout still stays 50dp high. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `configChanges` you are telling the system that you do not want to automatically switch layouts so you are stuck with only one layout for portrait and landscape.

You either have to fix your code so it works properly on orientation change or manually change the view that contains your ad to the alternate size\location when you rotate the device.

The best solution is usually to refactor your code so that the proper orientation procedure is enabled. i.e Not locking the configChanges attribute.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setContentView` in `onConfigurationChanged` to switch layouts

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```